# git tag should not fail if tag is already in the commit I want to tag

Tags: git, bash

Part of our CI is to tag our repo using the version specified in a `version.txt` file. We simply do:

```
git tag `cat version.txt`
```

Since we have no way of automatically increasing the version (there is no way to know if we are doing a major or minor release), updating the `version.txt` file is left to the individual developer. Which means errors can and do happen.

What we want is:

1. if the version has been updated, the repo should be tagged and deployed.
2. if the version has not been updated, the CI cycle should fail.
3. *but* if the CI cycle is manually restarted, this should run smoothly

Requirement 3 could be easily satisfied if `git tag` was not failing whenever I want to tag the current commit with a tag it already has.

That is, `git tag 1.2.3` fails if tag `1.2.3` is already in an old commit (good), but it *also* fails if it is in the commit I want to tag (bad).

Is there a way of telling `git tag` not to fail if I want to tag the current commit with one of the tags it already has?

Otherwise I will need to implement this feature myself, by getting the commit the tag refers to, and checking it against current commit in HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

Before tagging, check if the current commit already has that tag.

```
git tag -l --points-at HEAD <tag>
```

> *Since we have no way of automatically increasing the version (there is no way to know if we are doing a major or minor release), updating the version.txt file is left to the individual developer. Which means errors can and do happen.*

When I have implemented such a system, I've defaulted the release to a minor one. So, by default, 1.2.3 becomes 1.2.4. I've also left a final manual step between "prepare for release" and "do the release" to allow verification.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the tag already given in a previous commit. Same tag in different commit git doesn't allow and also don't need I think.

```
$ git tag -d <tag-name>                       # delete the tag from local
$ git push origin :refs/tags/<tag-name>       # delete a tag from remote 
$ git tag <cat version.txt>                   # give a new tag on current commit
$ git push --tags                             # push tag
```

Comment: Don't do this: Git *assumes* tags are permanent and unchanging. If someone deletes a tag and then re-tags, everyone else who *already has* the tag will retain the *old* tag-value. To pick up the new one, they must *also* delete and re-create the tag. So if you have 1000 users, you will be making 1000 people run 2000 commands (one delete, and one create).